# (Im)perfect forwarding with variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, sfinae, variadic-functions

## Synopsis

Given a type with a variadic template constructor that forwards the arguments to an implementation class, is it possible to restrict the types being forwarded with SFINAE?

## Details

First, consider the non-variadic case with a constructor taking a universal reference. Here one can disable forwarding of a non-const lvalue reference via SFINAE to use the copy constructor instead.

```
struct foo
{
  foo() = default;
  
  foo(foo const&) 
  {
      std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
  }

  template <
    typename T,
    typename Dummy = typename std::enable_if<
      !std::is_same<
          T,
          typename std::add_lvalue_reference<foo>::type
      >::value
    >::type
  >
  foo(T&& x)
    : impl(std::forward<T>(x))
  {
      std::cout << "uref" << std::endl;
  }

  foo_impl impl;
};
```

This restriction of the universal reference is useful because otherwise the implementation class would receive a non-const lvalue reference of type `foo`, which it does not know about.
Full example [at LWS](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304221013/http://liveworkspace.org/code/32662d3222396202a9bdb6e9703bc8d1).

## Question

But how does this work with variadic templates? Is it possible at all? If so, how? The naive extension does not work:

```
template <
  typename... Args,
  typename Dummy = typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_same<
        Args...,
        typename std::add_lvalue_reference<foo>::type
    >::value
  >::type
>
foo(Args&&... args)
  : impl(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
{
    std::cout << "uref" << std::endl;
}
```

(Also [at LWS](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305062022/http://liveworkspace.org/code/98da783837eb749ff561b45792a9f3fe).)

*EDIT:* I found that R. Martinho Fernandez blogged about a variation of this issue in 2012: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20141205121901/http://flamingdangerzone.com:80/cxx11/2012/06/05/is_related.html)

Comment: @LucDanton: Yeah, that's exactly what I was looking for. If you formulate it as an answer, I'll take that one. I [tested it on LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/661bbf01c42aa18005d94328ab50de57).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here are the different ways to write a properly constrained constructor template, in increasing order of complexity and corresponding increasing order of feature-richness and decreasing order of number of gotchas.

[This particular form of EnableIf](https://rmf.io/cxx11/almost-static-if/) will be used but this is an implementation detail that doesn't change the essence of the techniques that are outlined here. It's also assumed that there are `And` and `Not` aliases to combine different metacomputations. E.g. `And<std::is_integral<T>, Not<is_const<T>>>` is more convenient than `std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_integral<T>::value && !is_const<T>::value>`.

I don't recommend any particular strategy, because *any* constraint is much, much better than no constraint at all when it comes to constructor templates. If possible, avoid the first two techniques which have very obvious drawbacks -- the rest are elaborations on the same theme.

### Constrain on self

```
template<typename T>
using Unqualified = typename std::remove_cv<
    typename std::remove_reference<T>::type
>::type;

struct foo {
    template<
        typename... Args
        , EnableIf<
            Not<std::is_same<foo, Unqualified<Args>>...>
        >...
    >
    foo(Args&&... args);
};
```

**Benefit:** avoids the constructor from participating in overload resolution in the following scenario:

```
foo f;
foo g = f; // typical copy constructor taking foo const& is not preferred!
```

**Drawback**: participates in *every* other kind of overload resolution

### Constrain on construction expression

Since the constructor has the moral effects of constructing a `foo_impl` from `Args`, it seems natural to express the constraints on those exact terms:

```
    template<
        typename... Args
        , EnableIf<
            std::is_constructible<foo_impl, Args...>
        >...
    >
    foo(Args&&... args);
```

**Benefit:** This is now officially a constrained template, since it only participates in overload resolution if some semantic condition is met.

**Drawback:** Is the following valid?

```
// function declaration
void fun(foo f);
fun(42);
```

If, for instance, `foo_impl` is `std::vector<double>`, then yes, the code is valid. Because `std::vector<double> v(42);` is a valid way to *construct* a vector of such type, then it is valid to *convert* from `int` to `foo`. In other words, `std::is_convertible<T, foo>::value == std::is_constructible<foo_impl, T>::value`, putting aside the matter of other constructors for `foo` (mind the swapped order of parameters -- it is unfortunate).

#### Constrain on construction expression, explicitly

Naturally, the following comes immediately to mind:

```
    template<
        typename... Args
        , EnableIf<
            std::is_constructible<foo_impl, Args...>
        >...
    >
    explicit foo(Args&&... args);
```

A second attempt that marks the constructor `explicit`.

**Benefit:** Avoids the above drawback! And it doesn't take much either -- as long as you don't forget that `explicit`.

**Drawbacks:** If `foo_impl` is `std::string`, then the following may be inconvenient:

```
void fun(foo f);
// No:
// fun("hello");
fun(foo { "hello" });
```

It depends on whether `foo` is for instance meant to be a thin wrapper around `foo_impl`. Here is what I think is a more annoying drawback, assuming `foo_impl` is `std::pair<int, double*>`.

```
foo make_foo()
{
    // No:
    // return { 42, nullptr };
    return foo { 42, nullptr };
}
```

I don't feel like `explicit` actually saves me from anything here: there are two arguments in the braces so it's obviously not a conversion, and the type `foo` already appears in the signature, so I'd like to spare with it when I feel it is redundant. `std::tuple` suffers from that problem (although factories like `std::make_tuple` do ease that pain a bit).

### Separately constrain conversion from construction

Let's separately express *construction* and *conversion* constraints:

```
// New trait that describes e.g.
// []() -> T { return { std::declval<Args>()... }; }
template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct is_perfectly_convertible_from: std::is_constructible<T, Args...> {};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_perfectly_convertible_from: std::is_convertible<U, T> {};

// New constructible trait that will take care that as a constraint it
// doesn't overlap with the trait above for the purposes of SFINAE
template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_perfectly_constructible
: And<
    std::is_constructible<T, U>
    , Not<std::is_convertible<U, T>>
> {};
```

Usage:

```
struct foo {
    // General constructor
    template<
        typename... Args
        , EnableIf< is_perfectly_convertible_from<foo_impl, Args...> >...
    >
    foo(Args&&... args);

    // Special unary, non-convertible case
    template<
        typename Arg
        , EnableIf< is_perfectly_constructible<foo_impl, Arg> >...
    >
    explicit foo(Arg&& arg);
};
```

**Benefit:** Construction and conversion of `foo_impl` are now necessary and sufficient conditions for construction and conversion of `foo`. That is to say, `std::is_convertible<T, foo>::value == std::is_convertible<T, foo_impl>::value` and `std::is_constructible<foo, Ts...>::value == std::is_constructible<foo_impl, T>::value` both hold (almost).

**Drawback?** `foo f { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };` doesn't work if `foo_impl` is e.g. `std::vector<int>`, because the constraint is in terms of a construction of the style `std::vector<int> v(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);`. It is possible to add a further overload taking `std::initializer_list<T>` that is constrained on `std::is_convertible<std::initializer_list<T>, foo_impl>` (left as an exercise to the reader), or even an overload taking `std::initializer_list<T>, Ts&&...` (constraint also left as an exercise to the reader -- but remember that 'conversion' from more than one argument is not a construction!). Note that we don't need to modify `is_perfectly_convertible_from` to avoid overlap.

The more obsequious amongst us will also make sure to discriminate *narrow* conversions against the other kind of conversions.

Comment: For your "Constrain on self" advice, you should be using `std::is_base_of` instead of `std::is_same`. See [Universal References and the Copy Constructor](http://ericniebler.com/2013/08/07/universal-references-and-the-copy-constructo/).

Comment: @EricNiebler Thanks for the notification. You're right, this answer is due for an upgrade. I need some time to figure it all out though.

Comment: @EricNiebler I still have some reservations. E.g. `std::is_base_of<foo, std::tuple<foo>>()` holds for a non-`final` `foo` class type with the libstdc++ implementation I'm using, and yet we wouldn't want the copy/move special members to catch such tuples. (Bear with me this contrived scenario of a `foo` being constructible from `std::tuple<foo>` from a generic constructor.) Is there a finer-grained relation than 'being a base of' we can use?

Comment: A thought occurs: it is possible to 'intervene' and manually perform overloading: refuse those arguments that are convertible to `wrapper const&` or `wrapper&&` (and leave them to be caught by the special members). (A neighbouring Standard concept is that of reference related types -- although it doesn't take into account accessibility.)

Comment: @EricNiebler I'm not too sure what to make of this answer anymore, but I did start [a discussion on one of the isocpp.org groups](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/0ASX51FikXs) -- somewhat framed in the context of future Standard Library components.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand `EnableIf<std::is_constructible<foo_impl, Args...>>...` from the first example. Is this declaring a non-type template parameter pack (as the first `...` already expanded `Args`)? Why does it need to be a parameter pack?

Comment: @HighCommander4 That is correct — it needs to be a pack to be deducible. You can read more about [various flavors of `EnableIf`](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/06/01/almost-static-if.html).

Comment: @LucDanton: Interesting. I typically use `EnableIf<...>* = nullptr`.

Answer (score 4):

You can put `Args` inside more complex expressions and expand this like `expression(Args)...`. Therefore

```
!std::is_same<Args, typename std::add_lvalue_reference<foo>::type>::value...
```

Will give you a comma seperated list of `is_same` for each argument. You could use that as template arguments to a template combining the values accordingly, giving you something like the following.

```
template<bool... Args> struct and_;

template<bool A, bool... Args>
struct and_<A, Args...>{
  static constexpr bool value = A && and_<Args...>::value;
};
template<bool A>
struct and_<A>{
  static constexpr bool value = A;
};

//...
template <typename... Args,
          typename Dummy = typename std::enable_if<
              and_<!std::is_same<Args, 
                                 typename std::add_lvalue_reference<foo>::type
                                >::value...>::value
              >::type
         >
foo(Args&&... args) : impl(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
{
  std::cout << "uref" << std::endl;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how exactly you want to restrict the arguments. Therefore I'm not sure if this will do what you want, but the you should be able to use the principle.

Comment: +1 And if more than one type needs to be blacklisted, one could use [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/libs/mpl/)'s `boost::mpl::vector<>` and `boost::mpl::contains`.

Comment: This [works](http://liveworkspace.org/code/a420e3f3a8b76315a6620f9cfd143551), thanks. Note though that the "universal constructor" using `T&&` is a better match than the copy constructor, as [this example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/5bd601c7226441baf755e0281d3de069) without the SFINAE restriction demonstrates.

Comment: You should be using `std::is_base_of` instead of `std::is_same`. See [Universal References and the Copy Constructor](http://ericniebler.com/2013/08/07/universal-references-and-the-copy-constructo/).