# How can I prevent a variadic constructor from being preferred to the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, variadic-templates

I have a template 'Foo', which owns a T, and I'd like it to have a variadic constructor that forwards its arguments to T's constructor:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {

    Foo()
        : t() {}

    Foo(const Foo& other)
        : t(other.t) {}

    template<typename ...Args>
    Foo(Args&&... args)
        : t(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    T t;
};
```

However, this causes Foo to not be copyable:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Foo<std::shared_ptr<int>> x(new int(42));
    decltype(x) copy_of_x(x);  // FAILS TO COMPILE
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

because, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953611), the non-constness of the argument causes the variadic constructor to be a better match. I don't want to force my callers to use const_cast, for obvious reasons.

One possible solution I found was to write a "copy constructor" for Foo which takes a non-const Foo and uses constructor forwarding:

```
Foo(Foo& other)
    : Foo(const_cast<const Foo&>(other)) {}
```

When this constructor is defined, things work again: now the non-const Foo argument copy ctor is preferred. However, this seems very sketchy to me, in that this "cure" seems worse than the disease.

Is there another way to achieve this effect, to indicate that the natural copy constructor should be preferred to the variadic constructor? If not, are there any adverse consequences of defining this non-const argument copy constructor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are variadic constructors supposed to hide the implicitly generated ones?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953611/are-variadic-constructors-supposed-to-hide-the-implicitly-generated-ones)

Comment: My initial guess is that the only two solutions are either the extra overload for non-const, or some enable_if logic which excludes that case.  Personally, I would go with the addition of a non-const copy constructor.

Comment: @BoPersson Not really a duplicate. I'd read that question and answer (and even linked to it), but my question is more about whether declaring the non-const arg copy ctor as a workaround has adverse consequences.

Comment: Related usefulness: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13328507/1170277

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use some ugly SFINAE with `std::enable_if`, but I'm not sure it is better than your initial solution (in fact, I'm pretty sure it's worse!):

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

// helper that was not included in C++11
template<bool B, typename T = void> using disable_if = std::enable_if<!B, T>;

template<typename T>
struct Foo {

    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo &) = default;

    template<typename Arg, typename ...Args, typename = typename
        disable_if<
            sizeof...(Args) == 0 &&
            std::is_same<typename
                std::remove_reference<Arg>::type,
                Foo
            >::value
        >::type
    >
    Foo(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
        : t(std::forward<Arg>(arg), std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    T t;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Foo<std::shared_ptr<int>> x(new int(42));
    decltype(x) copy_of_x(x);
    decltype(x) copy_of_temp(Foo<std::shared_ptr<int>>(new int));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to need to ponder that one for a bit (typename = typename!), but I suspect your conclusion that this is worse is probably correct.

Comment: @acm: C++11 allows defaulted template parameters for functions, C++03 did not. It is a convenient place to apply `enable_if`.

Comment: @acm Augment the `enable_if` with a `sizeof...(Args) == 0` check possibly as well.  Ie, if there is 1 or more element in `Args`, it is enabled, and it is also enabled if the first element is not `Foo`.

Comment: @acm: Regarding `typename = typename ...`, it is "simply" an unnamed template parameter with a default value. See also this page on [the Lounge<C++> wiki](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks:enable-if-for-c-11).

Comment: @Yakk: indeed, the code I gave will fail if there are more than one parameter and the first one is a `Foo`. Let met correct that.

Comment: C++17 allows writing this more elegantly: `std::enable_if_t<!std::is_callable_v<std::decay_t<Foo(Foo const&)>(Args&&...)>>` (no need to separate `Arg&&` from `Args&&...`). We test whether an invented function with same "signature" as the copy constructor could be called with the arguments and, if so, suppress the variadic constructor.

Comment: Note: `is_callable` is now spelled `is_invocable` in C++17, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025661/is-stdis-callable-replaced-with-stdis-invocable-in-c17)

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to not do what you're doing.

That said, a simple fix is to let the variadic constructor forward up to a base class constructor, with some special first argument.

E.g. the following compiles with MinGW g++ 4.7.1:

```
#include <iostream>         // std::wcout, std::endl
#include <memory>           // std::shared_ptr
#include <stdlib.h>         // EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>          // std::forward

void say( char const* const s ) { std::wcout << s << std::endl; }

template<typename T>
struct Foo;

namespace detail {
    template<typename T>
    struct Foo_Base
    {
        enum Variadic { variadic };

        Foo_Base()
            : t()
        { say( "default-init" ); }

        Foo_Base( Foo_Base const& other )
            : t( other.t )
        { say( "copy-init" ); }

        template<typename ...Args>
        Foo_Base( Variadic, Args&&... args )
            : t( std::forward<Args>(args)... )
        { say( "variadic-init" ); }

        T t;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct Foo_ConstructorDispatch
        : public Foo_Base<T>
    {
        Foo_ConstructorDispatch()
            : Foo_Base<T>()
        {}

        template<typename ...Args>
        Foo_ConstructorDispatch( std::tuple<Foo<T>&>*, Args&&... args )
            : Foo_Base<T>( args... )
        {}

        template<typename ...Args>
        Foo_ConstructorDispatch( std::tuple<Foo<T> const&>*, Args&&... args )
            : Foo_Base<T>( args... )
        {}

        template<typename ...Args>
        Foo_ConstructorDispatch( void*, Args&&... args)
            : Foo_Base<T>( Foo_Base<T>::variadic, std::forward<Args>(args)... )
        {}
    };
}  // namespace detail

template<typename T>
struct Foo
    : public detail::Foo_ConstructorDispatch<T>
{
    template<typename ...Args>
    Foo( Args&&... args)
        : detail::Foo_ConstructorDispatch<T>(
            (std::tuple<Args...>*)0,
            std::forward<Args>(args)...
            )
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Foo<std::shared_ptr<int>>   x( new int( 42 ) );
    decltype(x)                 copy_of_x( x );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is an interesting approach. Unfortunately I think that in the case of the thing I am trying to build that the additional complexity is probably not helpful. I'll probably just remove the attempt to have the template constructor. While nice in certain ways, it clearly is more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: @acm: The "not do what you're doing" advice means to not directly pass all the variadic constructor arguments on to the contained thingy. You can still easily handle the *real problem* this way, but with e.g. a first argument that only says, pass this on to the contained thingy, please. Essentially, offer the user directly the `Foo_Base` class shown above, with **explicit** constructor choice, instead of the `Foo` class above with **implicit** (automated) constructor choice (which you asked for). Explicit = good, implicit = bad. Sorry to spell things out, but maybe it was not clear! :-)

Comment: There's one huge disadvantage to this interesting approach: None of default-ctor, copy-ctor and move-ctor can be trivial anymore...

Comment: @Deduplicator: I fail to see how it's a disadvantage that the forwarding constructor isn't trivial.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Well, some containers and algorithms special-case that for better performance.

Answer (score 2):

> If not, are there any adverse consequences of defining this non-const argument copy constructor?

I am going to ignore the "If not", since there *are* other approaches. But there *is* an adverse consequence of your approach. The following still uses the template constructor

```
Foo<X> g();
Foo<X> f(g());
```

Because `g()` is an rvalue, the template is a better match because it deduces the parameter to an rvalue reference.

Comment: Sure. I'd actually removed the move ctor when reducing the test case to make an example since I didn't want to make things more complex. At least with clang, it does not seem to select the template when Foo(Foo&&) is available.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the constructor when the argument type is the same type as or derived from this:

```
template<typename ThisType, typename ... Args>
struct is_this_or_derived : public std::false_type {};

template<typename ThisType, typename T>
struct is_this_or_derived<ThisType, T>
    : public std::is_base_of<std::decay_t<ThisType>, std::decay_t<T> >::type {};

template<typename ThisType, typename ... Args>
using disable_for_this_and_derived 
      = std::enable_if_t<!is_this_or_derived<ThisType, Args ...>::value>;
```

Use it as

```
template<typename ...Args
        , typename = disable_for_this_and_derived<Foo, Args ...> >
                                                //^^^^
                                                //this needs to be adjusted for each class
Foo(Args&&... args) : t(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`std::is_convertible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible).

Comment: @Deduplicator: I actually thought about adding another solution using `is_convertible`. It's easier to transfer between classes, but obviously not as general... if `T` can be constructed from a `Foo`, the `Foo(Foo&)` copy is shaded again.