# Why variadic template constructor matches better than copy constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, overload-resolution

The following code does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() { std::cout << "Foo()" << std::endl; }
    Foo(int) { std::cout << "Foo(int)" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T>
struct Bar
{
    Foo foo;

    Bar(const Bar&) { std::cout << "Bar(const Bar&)" << std::endl; }

    template <typename... Args>
    Bar(Args&&... args) : foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {
        std::cout << "Bar(Args&&... args)" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar<Foo> bar1{};
    Bar<Foo> bar2{bar1};
}
```

Compiler error suggest to me that compiler was trying to use variadic template constructor instead of copy constructor:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of 'Bar<T>::Bar(Args&& ...) [with Args = {Bar<Foo>&}; T = Foo]':
prog.cpp:27:20:   required from here
prog.cpp:18:55: error: no matching function for call to 'Foo::Foo(Bar<Foo>&)'
  Bar(Args&&... args) : foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
```

Why compiler does that and how to fix it?

Comment: The constructor template can deduce an lvalue-reference to *non-const* `Bar` which is a better match than the copy-constructor.

Comment: Because the universal constructor requires fewer conversions (i.e. none).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent a variadic constructor from being preferred to the copy constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937873/how-can-i-prevent-a-variadic-constructor-from-being-preferred-to-the-copy-constr)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This call:

```
Bar<Foo> bar2{bar1};
```

has two candidates in its overload set:

```
Bar(const Bar&);
Bar(Bar&);       // Args... = {Bar&}
```

One of the ways to determine if one conversion sequence is better than the other is, from [over.ics.rank]:

> Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence
>   S2 if
>
> — [...]
>   — S1 and S2 are reference bindings (8.5.3), and the types to which the references refer are the same
>   type except for top-level *cv*-qualifiers, and the type to which the reference initialized by S2 refers
>   is more *cv*-qualified than the type to which the reference initialized by S1 refers. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> int f(const int &);
> int f(int &);
> int g(const int &);
> int g(int);
>
> int i;
> int j = f(i);    // calls f(int &)
> int k = g(i);    // ambiguous
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

The forwarding reference variadic constructor is a better match because its reference binding (`Bar&`) is less *cv*-qualified than the copy constructor's reference binding (`const Bar&`).

As far as solutions, you could simply exclude from the candidate set anytime `Args...` is something that you should call the copy or move constructor with SFINAE:

```
template <typename... > struct typelist;

template <typename... Args,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<
              !std::is_same<typelist<Bar>,
                            typelist<std::decay_t<Args>...>>::value
          >>
Bar(Args&&... args)
```

If `Args...` is one of `Bar`, `Bar&`, `Bar&&`, `const Bar&`, then `typelist<decay_t<Args>...>` will be `typelist<Bar>` - and that's a case we want to exclude. Any other set of `Args...` will be allowed just fine.

Comment: C++11 version: template <typename... Args,
           typename = typename std::enable_if<
               !std::is_same<typelist<Bar>,
                             typelist<typename std::decay<Args>::type...>>::value
           >::type>

Comment: @kpx1894 no, the C++11 version is first write `decay_t` and `enable_if_t` in your own namespace, then use it instead of `std::` versions.

Answer (score 6):

While I agree that it's counter-intuitive, the reason is that your copy constructor takes a `const Bar&` but `bar1` is not const.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2622b4871d6407da

Since the universal reference can bind anything it is chosen over the more restrictive constructor with the const requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to avoid the variadic constructor being selected is to supply all forms of the `Bar` constructor.

It's a little more work, but avoids the complexity of enable_if, if that's important to you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() { std::cout << "Foo()" << std::endl; }
    Foo(int) { std::cout << "Foo(int)" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T>
struct Bar
{
    Foo foo;

    Bar(const Bar&) { std::cout << "Bar(const Bar&)" << std::endl; }
    Bar(Bar&) { std::cout << "Bar(Bar&)" << std::endl; }
    Bar(Bar&&) { std::cout << "Bar(Bar&&)" << std::endl; }

    template <typename... Args>
    Bar(Args&&... args) : foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {
        std::cout << "Bar(Args&&... args)" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar<Foo> bar1{};
    Bar<Foo> bar2{bar1};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "std-way" to solve this issue is to put a parameter of std::in_place_t first. That way you have a clear type to force the compiler to use the templated constructor when you want and to not let it match when you don't want. You could check the way it is done here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional.