# Is "std::is_callable" replaced with "std::is_invocable" in C++17?

Tags: c++, standards, language-design, c++17, type-traits

[cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_callable) has removed the entry page for `std::is_callable`, and use `std::is_invocable` entry page instead.

However, `std::is_callable` is still available in Visual Studio 2017.

Is `std::is_callable` formally [**replaced|deprecated|removed**] with `std::is_invocable` in C++17?

Comment: That seems to be the case, [yes](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta#type.synop).

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 v15.3 will rename std::is_callable to std::is_invocable

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, `is_callable` has been renamed `is_invocable` as described in [p0604r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0604r0.html). The paper includes the rationale for this decision:

> **Rename `is_callable` to `is_invocable`:** `is_callable` would be the most natural name for a trait that answers the question whether a function call expression would be valid or not, which is a strict subset of the expressions, *`INVOKE`* supports, furthermore the changed name `is_invocable` much clearer expresses its meaning. Releasing the name is_callable allows us in the future to possibly introduce a pure `is_callable` trait.

Comment: @ScY Copy-pasta screw up, somehow managed to paste the link twice; fixed now.

Comment: The real question is why they chose _invocable_ instead of _invokable_.

Comment: @isanae Ks skare kreators of language specifikations.

Comment: @isanae - well, invokable isn't a word in english, but invocable is.

Comment: @Batman `decltype`? `wchar_t`? `deque`? Who cares if `invokable` is valid English or not?

Comment: @isanae because it's `protected` and `class` not `prouetekted` and `klasse` because many people use english, and the one letter difference would just be an annoyance

Comment: @cat It's not English. It means "something on which you can perform an INVOKE operation" or, simply, something you can call `std::invoke`" on.

Comment: @isanae What is not English? *Invocable* is an adjective form of *invoke*, there is no such word as *invokable* in the language. So `is_invocable` does mean *is it something you can `invoke`?*.

Comment: "strict subset of the expressions etc." - What things are "invocable" but not "callable"?

Comment: @einpoklum — pointer-to-member-data.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Really? Can you invoke (a pointer to) member data?

Comment: @einpoklum -- yup; pointer-to-member-data is a [callable type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable). That's where the terminology is a bit sloppy; objects of **callable** types get **invoked**. My apologies. <g> (one other person whose name I've forgotten and I wrote the original versions of the "callable" and "INVOKE" stuff to unify four or five separate parts of what became the C++11 standard)

Comment: @PeteBecker: Suppose I have a `struct S { int x, y; };`. Can you give an example of how one "invokes" `&S::y`?

Comment: @einpoklum -- just as you'd imagine: `S s; std::invoke(&S::y, s);`. It's completely uniform: first argument is a callable object, the remaining arguments are the objects needed to "invoke" it. [Here's](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) a link to the description of "INVOKE", which gives the details. In particular, the part that begin with "Otherwise, if `N == 0`...".

Comment: @einpoklum -- yes, it's something of a weird corner. But "INVOKE" simplifies the descriptions of [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), [`std::mem_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn), etc. You could pass a pointer-to-member-data as the first argument to the constructor of `std::thread`, but that would be rather silly.