# What was the problem with std::is_callable?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, type-traits

Since 2017-03-13 `std::is_callable` is gone from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_callable). The last available description of it is from 2016-11-21 on [WaybackMachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20161121072930/https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_callable).

The main difference between `std::is_callable` and `std::is_invocable`, that replaced it, is that

- the former used a single template parameter `template <class FnArgs>` specialized to `FnArgs` = `Fn(Args...)` for the callable type `Fn` and for the parameter types to test (`Args...`), while
- the latter accepts all of these in separate template parameters (`template <class Fn, class... Args>`).

What was the problem with `std::is_callable`'s `Fn(Args...)` approach?

I understand, that `Fn(Args...)` is a function type, where `Fn` is the return type. `std::is_callable` gave `Fn` another meaning, the function type to test, which I find misleading. This is only one problem. Could you name all the rest?

What I can think of, but cannot put it together (in keywords):

- Not every type can be return or parameter type of a function, e.g. `void`, abstract classes, C arrays, function types, [abominable function types](https://wg21.link/P0172r0#2.1), incomplete types come to mind.
- In function parameters array and function types decay into pointers ([C++23 [dcl.fct]#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/dcl.fct#5.sentence-3)), and the top-level cv-qualifiers are discarded ([C++23 [dcl.fct]#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/dcl.fct#5.sentence-4)).
- I don't know, maybe the `Fn(Args...)` approach may introduce ambiguity in some cases.
- Changing `Fn(Args...)` to separate template parameters was proposed in [LWG2895](https://wg21.link/LWG2895).

I have found *one* compiler on Godbolt, on which `std::is_callable` works: [MVSC v19.10](https://godbolt.org/z/rshqxoKeq). The others say there is no such type in namespace `std`. Seeing it work helps to understand this type trait more deeply, e.g. Alisdair Meredith's example from [P0604r0](https://wg21.link/P0604r0#Rationale). See on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/156hGx7d5).

Comment: *"You earn a "bonus", if you show, how to get std::is_callable to work on Godbolt...."* If it's been renamed/removed etc then there's no point in making it work with godbolt. That wouldn't be a valid c++ program anymore.

Comment: Related: [Is "std::is_callable" replaced with "std::is_invocable" in C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025661/is-stdis-callable-replaced-with-stdis-invocable-in-c17)

Comment: Note that it works in msvc only because msvc by default **don't use** c++17(msvc uses c++14 by default afaik). If you set `/std:c++17` msvc will also start [rejecting](https://godbolt.org/z/EnnG73r8T) the code.

Answer (score 2):

> What was the problem with `std::is_callable`'s `Fn(Args...)` approach?

This can be answered from [P0604](https://wg21.link/P0604r0) (which renamed `is_callable`) bullet 3 that states:

> 3. *Replace function type encoding of type lists in is_callable and result_of:*
>
> **The function type encoding form used in these type traits is a relict from the pre-variadic template era** of C++ where a single type is used to express a list of types. ***First*, for both traits the natural interpretation of the encoded form `Fn(ArgTypes...)` looks as if `Fn` is used as return type, but it is only the callable object to which the arguments are provided. *Second*, contrary to the rest of all type traits which use a glvalue-based expression approach due to the direct usage of declval applied to the given type parameters, function type encoding is more natural for non-glvalues**. In particular, parameter types are first adjusted via a special decay-like mechanism ([8.3.5 [dcl.fct]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.fct)), such that the actually provided types are often not the types on which the actual test is applied. Another problem is that function return types and argument types prevent some important type classes to be actually provided in the encoded form: Neither can argument types have an abstract class type nor cv void type, nor can function types or array types be used as "return type".