# How delegate from copy constructor to universal copy constructor template?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, copy-constructor

If I want to write a universal copy constructor (one that will take any argument type), it's easy enough to do:

```
class Widget {
public:
  template<typename T> Widget(T&& other);
};
```

This won't prevent the compiler from generating a traditional copy constructor, so I'd like to write that myself and delegate to the template.  But how do I do that?

```
class Widget {
public:
  template<typename T> Widget(T&& other);
  Widget(const Widget& other): ??? {}         // how delegate to the template?
};
```

I tried to write the delegating constructor this way,

```
Widget(const Widget& other): Widget<const Widget&>(other){}
```

but VC11, gcc 4.8, and clang 3.2 all reject it.

How can I write the delegating copy constructor I'm trying to write?

Comment: For the copy-constructor, dropping the template argument and using `std::move` make it compile for me.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Clever. Lvalues are hence forwarded as rvalues, but they're const, so they can't be moved from.  Obscure, but it works!

Comment: Why do you even want this? If you have a greedy *converting* constructor (that's what it is, not a "universal copy constructor"), it usually has to do something radically different than what a true copy constructor does. Also, the usual problem is that you *don't* want the universal constructor to be called when you copy stuff.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296461/imperfect-forwarding-with-variadic-templates

Comment: @Xeo: Motivation is to avoid code duplication. If the templatized constructor uses tag dispatching to divide argument types into two or more categories (e.g., integral types should cause the constructor to find initialization arguments by index in a container, while non-integral types should be directly passed to a data member as an initialization argument), the copy constructor should forward its argument to the tag-dispatching function (the template) instead of duplicating part of the tag-dispatch logic itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can't specify template arguments for a constructor template; you're limited to deduction.  Maybe you can adapt an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9311802/1010226) from one of [my old posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9287250/1010226):

```
// NOT Tested!
#include <utility>

class Widget
{
    enum fwd_t { fwd };

    // Your true master constructor
    template< typename T >  Widget( fwd_t, T &&t );

public:
    template < typename T >
    Widget( T&& other );
        : Widget( fwd, std::forward<T>(other) )
    {}
    Widget( const Widget& other )
        : Widget( fwd, other )
    {}
};
```

The two single-argument constructors forward to a two-argument sibling constructor.

Comment: I actually like JoachimPileborg's suggestion (in his comment of 7 March 2013) better, because it doesn't involve introducing a new constructor, but your approach seems perfectly reasonable, too.