# C++ force instantiation of a template constructor of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor

Say I have a template class

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
    template<typename U>
        Foo(const Foo<U> &foo) {
            ...
        }
}
```

Obviously, `Foo<T>(const Foo<T>&)` is an instance of that template member, but for some reason C++ chooses to use the implicit copy constructor instead of instantiating this copy constructor from the template.

Is there a way to force the copy constructor to be instantiated from the template?

Usually, something like

```
template<> template<> Foo<int>::Foo(const Foo<int>&);
```

would work if I want a *specific* instance, but I want every `Foo<T>` that gets instantiated to also have `Foo(const Foo<T>&)` be instantiated as well.

How can I achieve this?

Without actually writing out `Foo::Foo(const Foo&);` separately, using the same exact code, of course. That would be silly.

Comment: You mean, the copy ctor is not executed (not even generated, that is) although you do copy-construct objects, like `Foo<int>j; Foo<int> i{j}`?

Comment: Well the implicit one is generated, which just copies all the members directly.

Comment: This will probably solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264252/how-delegate-from-copy-constructor-to-universal-copy-constructor-template

Comment: That does solve my problem (in fact, it's what I already did). I'm just asking if there's a specific way to force an instantiation.